# Reduce or eliminate normal map aliasing?

Tags: three.js

I've been trying normal maps using the Phong material, and along with specular and environment maps it's looking pretty nice. However the normal maps seem to be causing some pretty bad aliasing (see building at left in [this example](http://www.spacejack.ca/h5tt/img/screenshots/normal-aliasing.jpg)).

[Here is the normal map](http://www.spacejack.ca/h5tt/data/tex/building01_normal.png) I used. I tried softening it with a gaussian blur but it didn't have much effect. It looks great up close but at medium to far distances the aliasing looks pretty harsh, especially in motion.

Is there a property or option I should be using in THREE.js to minimize this? Anisotropy doesn't seem to help. I'm loading textures with: `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(url, null, success, error)`

Comment: I was going to ask if your texture is a power of 2, but i see that it is. I'm not really sure where this is coming from, but it might be a mip map issue. I'd expect it to look blurry at this distance, not as jagged as it is. Can you check if your texture is generating mip maps?

Comment: Yeah, fairly sure. I tried some other settings for Texture.minFilter like LinearFilter or NearestFilter and they have horrible aliasing. generateMipmaps is set to true and LinearMipMapLinearFilter looks the best by far. But it still has some nasty aliasing along straight edges it seems, even if they are 'soft'.

Comment: It looks like the aliasing is a result of extreme angles in the normal map, which become even more problematic with high specular values. If I flatten the relief shapes by 50%, a lot of the aliasing goes away. Also after doing some more searching, it looks as though normal map mipmap generation is a bit of an artform in itself.

Comment: Did you try normalizing your normal map? Nvidia has a plugin for photoshop that can do this